# How to change a 2 gang switch to a smart switch

Tags: smart-switch

I want to change my 2 gang switch to a smart switch. There are two lights connected to 2 gang switch and now I'm changing to a smart switch with also 2 switches. How can I do it?
[image: switch]

Comment: do you have a neutral in that box?

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and can you post a photo looking into the back of the box please?